# Run Action Upon Mouse Click and Mouse Release

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I am working on a Windows Form C# project that requires running code when a user clicks down on a button, then waiting, and running a different set of code when the user then releases the mouse button. I have tried Button1.MouseDown and MouseUp as something that was suggested when I did a search for this information, but neither of these worked.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did the MouseDown/MouseUp events not work? It sounds like the correct approach.

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to do and what isn't working, as it stands right now you have not given anything concrete enough to make more than a guess of what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual studios, try clicking on the button and in properties, view the "Events" menu.  You may have to scroll down and find Events "MouseDown" and Events "MouseUp".

Double click on each of this, which will load the class to work with.

Inside of those, you may add your code.

You can create a timer if you wish running at 100ms and if the user clicks the button and holds, then the timer goes and the moment he releases, inside that, you could have timer1.stop();

Comment: For some reason, this worked, unlike what I tried before. Thanks.